# angularjs drag and sort divs

Tags: html, angularjs

Can anyone please help me out with simple example of drag and reordering of divs using angularjs?

```
<div id="abc" style = width:20px;height:20px; background:red>
     ABC
</div>
<div id="xyz" style = width:20px;height:20px;background:blue>
     XYZ
</div>
```

These are 2 horizontal squares.. I want to drag and swap their positions.If I am dragging red box at blue box position then blue one should be shifted to to red's position.
Can it be done with angularjs? I had seen some list reordering examples but very tricky to understand..If someone can give me simple example will be very helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a drag and drop plugin (it also works for resizing)? It will simplify your problem I guess.

This one works like a charm: [Gridster](http://gridster.net/)

Example:

```
<div class="gridster">
    <ul>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
            <div id="abc" style = width:20px;height:20px; background:red>
                ABC
            </div>
        </li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
            <div id="xyz" style = width:20px;height:20px;background:blue>
                XYZ
           </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```